# putting an image tag into html expandable tree

Tags: jquery, html, xml, image, tree

I am converting an XML tree into an expandable HTML tree. the code is working. However, what I want to replace the `-` and `+` signs with JPEG images such as

http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/bullet_zpsblghj3ip.gif

I am trying to place the link as a href at the place of the `<b>-</b>` but its not working. usually I use a style of

```
background: transparent url(http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/bullet_zpsblghj3ip.gif) no-repeat top left;
```

but it wont work here. what do I do? thanks
this is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cd_catalog2.xml",
                    success: function (tree) {
                        traverse($('#treeView li'), tree.firstChild)
                        // this – is an &mdash;
                        $('<b>–<\/b>').prependTo('#treeView li:has(li)').click(function () {
                            var sign = $(this).text()
                            if (sign == "–")
                                $(this).text('+').next().children().hide()
                            else
                                $(this).text('–').next().children().show()
                        })
                    }
                })
            });
            function traverse(node, tree) {
                var children = $(tree).children()
                node.append(tree.nodeName)
                if (children.length) {
                    var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                    children.each(function () {
                        var li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                        traverse(li, this)
                    })
                } else {
                    $('<ul><li>' + $(tree).text() + '<\/li><\/ul>').appendTo(node)
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #treeView li{list-style: none;}
            #treeView ul { padding-left: 1em; }
            #treeView b { padding-right: 1em; }
        </style>
        <title>treeView</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="treeView">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the `json data` you are getting?

Comment: output on local server: –CATALOG–CD+TITLE

+ARTIST




–COUNTRYUSA

+COMPANY

–PRICE10.90

–YEAR

Comment: Not much helpfull!! Attach a screenshot of `json data` if possible!!

Comment: yea but im not using json here :p xml data. here we go: where do u attach here

Comment: here it is: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml just using this as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I have not fetched the list from the file its just a static example.

```
$('#treeView li:has(li)').addClass("Max").click(function (e) {
   $(this).toggleClass("Max Min")
   $(this).children().toggle()
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

The Css

```
.Min{
    background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
    padding-left : 20px;
}
.Max{
    background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat ;
    padding-left : 20px;
}
```

Here is a similar example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ace/8qd2xurm/)

**[EDIT]**

Updated script to match your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "cd_catalog.xml",
                success: function (tree) {
                    traverse($('#treeView li'), tree.firstChild)
                    $('#treeView li:has(li)').click(function (e) {
                        var cls = this.className.replace("Max","").replace("Min","")
                        $(this).toggleClass(cls+"Max "+cls+"Min")
                       $(this).children().toggle()
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    })
                }
            })
        });


        function traverse(node, tree) {
            var children = $(tree).children()
            node.addClass(tree.nodeName+"Max")
            node.append(tree.nodeName)
            if (children.length) {
                var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                children.each(function () {
                    var li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                    traverse(li, this)
                })
            } else {
                $('<ul><li>' + $(tree).text() + '<\/li><\/ul>').appendTo(node)
            }
        }
```

The Css for few of the tags

```
.CDMin{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
        .CDMax{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat ;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
        .CATALOGMin{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
        .CATALOGMax{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat ;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
        .ARTISTMin{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
        .ARTISTMax{
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat ;
            padding-left : 20px;
        }
```

I hope this helps

Sample example without ajax [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ace/cLa7vz61/)

Comment: this is working perfectly fine thanks! if I want to add such image to sub children depending on their TagName in the xml file, can you suggest something that I can do?

Comment: @MikeYounes you mean, add a different image for CATALOG and different image for CD, etc. You could try to do it when traversing the tree.

Comment: this is the problem im facing. I have written another code where I can input the xml structure as it is using divisions and convert it using document writes in a while loop

Comment: for loop sorry. and then I can use div.mytree div.parentofdiv {
cursor:pointer;
background:transparent url(http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
div.mytree div.expandedofdiv {
background:transparent url(http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif) no-repeat top left;
} in the style so as to change the elements pictures.

Comment: however, I don't know how to place pictures according to TAG NAME while traversing. this will make each CD has its own picture, CATALOG have its own picture, Artist its own, independent of parent or child relation

Comment: so im using this code instead which does not depend on divisions, but I have no idea how to do what I still need

Comment: @Mike I have edited my answer to work with different class for different tag. Let me know how it works.

Comment: I managed to do it in another way. i still have 1 problem can u check this out? :p
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828159/how-to-assign-a-link-to-a-branch-in-the-xml-so-that-it-opens-once-i-click-on-it