# how to assign a link to a branch in the xml so that it opens once i click on it in the output of the html

Tags: html, xml, hyperlink

This code converts an xml file to an html expandable tree:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "stations10.xml",
        success: function(tree) {
          traverse($('#treeView li'), tree.firstChild)
            // this – is an &mdash;
          $('#treeView li:has(li)').addClass("Max").click(function(e) {
            $(this).toggleClass("Max Min");
            $(this).children().toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
          })
          $('#treeView li').click(function(g) {

            var mytree2 = $(this);
            mytree2.children('li').toggle();

            g.stopPropagation();
          })

          $('<b></b>').prependTo('#treeView li:has(li)').click(function() {
            var sign = $(this).text()
            if (sign == "–")
              $(this).text('').next().children().hide()
            else
              $(this).text('').next().children().show()
          })
        }
      })
    });

    function traverse(node, tree) {
      var children = $(tree).children()
      node.addClass(tree.nodeName).append(tree)
      if (children.length) {
        var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
        children.each(function() {
          var li=$('<li>').appendTo(ul)
          traverse(li, this)
        })
      } else {
        $('<ul><li>' + $(tree).text() + '<\/li><\/ul>')
      }
    }
  </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #treeView li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    #treeView ul {
      padding-left: 1em;
    }

    #treeView b {
      padding-right: 1em;
    }

    .Min {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    li {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/bullet_zpsblghj3ip.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .MainStation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/station_zpswxz6gpqe.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .Substation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/sub_zpsspl8dckt.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .Control.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/control_zpsrfvdzyzp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .PushButton.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/pusbutton_zpsspjfsfsp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .ElectricStation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/electrical-safety-symbol_zpssdvscba0.gif") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
  </style>
    <title>treeView</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul id="treeView">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MAIN xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> MAIN
<MainStation 
        xlink:type="extended" 
        xlink:href="http://google.com"
        xlink:show="new"> Mainstation1
    <Substation> Substation1
        <Control>Control1</Control>
        <Control>Control2<MiniControl>MiniControl1</MiniControl><MiniControl>MiniControl2</MiniControl></Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1</PushButton>
    </Substation>
    <Substation> Substation2
        <Control>Control1<MiniControl>MiniControl1</MiniControl><MiniControl>MiniControl2</MiniControl></Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1</PushButton>
    </Substation>
    <Substation> Substation3
        <Control>Control1</Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <Control>Control3</Control>
        <Control>Control4</Control>
    </Substation>
    <Substation> Substation4
        <PushButton>PushButton1</PushButton>
        <PushButton>PushButton2</PushButton>
    </Substation>
</MainStation>  
<MainStation> Mainstation2
    <Substation> Substation1
        <Control>Control1</Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1</PushButton>
    </Substation>
    <Substation> Substation2
        <Control>Control1<MiniControl>MiniControl1</MiniControl><MiniControl>MiniControl2</MiniControl></Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1<MiniPushButton>MiniPushButton1</MiniPushButton><MiniPushButton>MiniPushButton2</MiniPushButton></PushButton>
    </Substation>
</MainStation>  
<ElectricStation> ElectricStation1
    <Substation> Substation1
        <Control>Control1</Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1</PushButton>
    </Substation>
    <Substation> Substation2
        <Control>Control1<MiniControl>MiniControl1</MiniControl><MiniControl>MiniControl2</MiniControl></Control>
        <Control>Control2</Control>
        <PushButton>PushButton1<MiniPushButton>MiniPushButton1</MiniPushButton><MiniPushButton>MiniPushButton2</MiniPushButton></PushButton>
    </Substation>
</ElectricStation>  
</MAIN>
```

As you can see, I tried linking the main station node to Google so that when I click on it in the output, it opens Google. However it's not working.

Comment: you want the link as well as expandable for the nodes?

Comment: ace thank youuuu. i might have a change at this now :p

Comment: as u can see i added a link reference in the 5th line of the XML file, to Mainstation, however its not giving me anything. attached is a screenshot of this code (where the xml that was altered insignificantly). what i want is that when i double click on Mainstation, it opens the google webpage

Comment: well actually i cant post an image, i dont have enough reputation. its simple. i have a tree, when i click on a node, it shows the children branches. i want to know how to assign a link to a branch so that when i click on that branch in the expandable tree, it opens the link. i tried using CDATA and Xlink. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change the script for expanding.

Here is one way you could do it. I have appended a span tag, this is to display the images. I have added the click handler to collapse and expand to this. So you will have to click exactly on the image to expand or collapse the list. The second handler is for the tags with href attribute. On click of the list with the href attribute it will redirect to the link location.

Note: I have changed the xlink:href attribute in the XML to just href.

**[EDIT]**

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "stations10.xml",
                    success: function(tree) {
                        traverse($('#treeView li'), tree.firstChild)
                        $('<span><\/span>').addClass("Max").prependTo('#treeView li:has(li)')
                        $('.Max,.Min').click(function (e) {
                            $(this).toggleClass("Max Min")
                            $(this).siblings().next().toggle()
                        });
                        $("[href]").click(function(){
                            window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")
                        });
                    }
                })
            });

            function traverse(node, tree) {
                var children = $(tree).children()
                node.addClass(tree.nodeName).append(tree)
                if (children.length) {
                    var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                    children.each(function() {
                        var li=$('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                        traverse(li, this)
                    })
                } else {
                    $('<ul><li>' + $(tree).text() + '<\/li><\/ul>')
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #treeView li {
            list-style: none;
        }

        #treeView ul {
        padding-left: 1em;
        }

        #treeView b {
            padding-right: 1em;
        }

        .Min {
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        .Max {
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        li {
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/bullet_zpsblghj3ip.gif") no-repeat;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        .MainStation.Max {
            background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/station_zpswxz6gpqe.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-size: 15px 15px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
        .Substation.Max {
          background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/sub_zpsspl8dckt.jpg") no-repeat;
          background-size: 15px 15px;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
        .Control.Max {
          background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/control_zpsrfvdzyzp.jpg") no-repeat;
          background-size: 15px 15px;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
        .PushButton.Max {
          background:     URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/pusbutton_zpsspjfsfsp.jpg") no-repeat;
          background-size: 15px 15px;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
        .ElectricStation.Max {
          background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/electrical-safety-symbol_zpssdvscba0.gif") no-repeat;
          background-size: 15px 15px;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding-left: 30px;
        }
        </style>
        <title>treeView</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="treeView">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The change in XML code

```
<MainStation 
        xlink:type="extended" 
        href="http://google.com"
        xlink:show="new"> Mainstation1
        ....
```

Comment: not working. what should the whole code be? you removed many elements from the script

Comment: you know, i actually tried adding just  $("[href]").click(function(){
                    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")
                }); and i seem to be getting something

Comment: got it to work and added style to the links by adding another class.

Comment: cheers man good thing theres people like you here to pull us out of our misery.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: So did you use this or found your own way to solve it?

Comment: I used the window.location.href part, without span.

Comment: its working fine. 
 
$("[href]").addClass("Blue").click(function(){
    
$(this).toggleClass("Purple");
window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")
     
 })

this is what I changed. I was getting the classes to work yesterday, but today theyre not changing colors dno why strange -_-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875963/convert-xml-to-json-while-keeping-code-working

Comment: this is the whole code. im new to using xml and json sorry, I did the html code on my own but needed help for the hyperlinks in xml and now completely new to json