# convert xml to json while keeping code working

Tags: html, json, xml, tree, converters

I have a xml file, and an html file associated with it. 
the html file takes the xml elements and outputs a tree with hyperlinks and pictures for each node type included. how can I convert the code to work for JSON instead of XML. this is the code and the xml

I added a function to attr elements so it opens a table when I click on it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "converted14.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(tree) {
                    traverse($('#treeView'), tree)
                    $('#treeView li:has(li)').addClass("Max").click(function(e) {
                            $(this).toggleClass("Max Min");
                            $(this).children("ul").toggle();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                    })

                    $("[href]").addClass("Blue").click(function(e){
                        $(this).toggleClass("Purple");
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")
                    })
                    $('#treeView li').click(function(g) {
                        var mytree2 = $(this);
                        mytree2.children('li').toggle();
                        g.stopPropagation();
                    })
                }
            })
        });
        function traverse(node, o) {
            for (var i in o) {
                if(i == "__text" || i == "_href" || i == "_attr")
                    continue;
                if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
                    if(o[i].__text){ 
                        var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                        var node=$('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                        if(o[i]._href){
                           var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                            $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
                    }
                        else{
                            $(node).text(o[i].__text)
                        }
                    if(o[i]._attr){

                            var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                            $(n).text(o[i]._attr)
                            $(n).hide()
                            $(n).parent().click(function(g){
                            $(n).toggle().addClass("Table")
                            })

                    }
                    }
                    traverse(node,o[i]);
                }
                else{
                    var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                    if(o[i].__text){
                        var li = $('<li>' + o[i].__text + '<\/li>').appendTo(ul)
                        if(o[i]._href){
                            var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                            $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
                        }

                    }else{
                            $('<li>' + o[i] + '</li>').appendTo(ul)
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #treeView li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    #treeView ul {
      padding-left: 1em;
    }

    #treeView b {
      padding-right: 1em;
    }

    .Min {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/plus_zps8o4adn0e.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .Blue {
    text-decoration: underline;
      color: Blue;
    }
    .Purple {
    text-decoration: underline;
      color: Purple;
    }

    .Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/minus_zpsk0jlvbaa.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    li {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/bullet_zpsblghj3ip.gif") no-repeat;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .Table {

    background-color : yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;    
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    }

    .MainStation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/station_zpswxz6gpqe.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .Substation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/sub_zpsspl8dckt.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .ControlExpandable.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/control_zpsrfvdzyzp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .PushButtonExpandable.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/pusbutton_zpsspjfsfsp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .Control {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/control_zpsrfvdzyzp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .PushButton {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/pusbutton_zpsspjfsfsp.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .ElectricStation.Max {
      background: URL("http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o747/Mike_Younes/electrical-safety-symbol_zpssdvscba0.gif") no-repeat;
      background-size: 15px 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
  </style>
    <title>treeView</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="treeView">
    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

and heres the json file again. only 1 line added to test the attr:

```
{
    "MAIN": {
        "MainStation": [
            {
                "Substation": [
                    {
                        "Control": "Control1\n",
                        "ControlExpandable": {
                            "MiniControl": [
                                "MiniControl1",
                                "MiniControl2"
                            ],
                            "__text": "Control2"

                        },
                        "PushButton": {

                            "__text": "PushButton1",
                            "_attr": "success\nDate:17july"
                        },
                        "_href": "http://google.com",
                        "__text": " Substation1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "ControlExpandable": {
                            "MiniControl": [
                                "MiniControl1",
                                "MiniControl2"
                            ],
                            "__text": "Control1"
                        },
                        "Control": "Control2",
                        "PushButton": "PushButton1",
                        "__text": " Substation2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Control": [
                            "Control1",
                            "Control2",
                            "Control3",
                            "Control4"
                        ],
                        "__text": " Substation3\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "PushButton": [
                            "PushButton1",
                            "PushButton2"
                        ],
                        "__text": " Substation4\n\n\n\n\n"
                    }
                ],
                "__text": " Mainstation1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
            },
            {
                "Substation": [
                    {
                        "Control": [
                            "Control1",
                            "Control2"
                        ],
                        "PushButton": "PushButton1",
                        "__text": " Substation1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "ControlExpandable": {
                            "MiniControl": [
                                "MiniControl1",
                                "MiniControl2"
                            ],
                            "__text": "Control1"
                        },
                        "Control": "Control2",
                        "PushButtonExpandable": {
                            "MiniPushButton": [
                                "MiniPushButton1",
                                "MiniPushButton2"
                            ],
                            "__text": "PushButton1"
                        },
                        "__text": " Substation2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                    }
                ],
                "__text": " Mainstation2\n\n\n\n\n"
            }
        ],
        "ElectricStation": {
            "Substation": [
                {
                    "Control": [
                        "Control1",
                        "Control2"
                    ],
                    "PushButton": "PushButton1",
                    "__text": " Substation1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                },
                {
                    "ControlExpandable": {
                        "MiniControl": [
                            "MiniControl1",
                            "MiniControl2"
                        ],
                        "__text": "Control1"
                    },
                    "Control": "Control2",
                    "PushButtonExpandable": {
                        "MiniPushButton": [
                            "MiniPushButton1",
                            "MiniPushButton2"
                        ],
                        "__text": "PushButton1"
                    },
                    "__text": " Substation2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                }
            ],
            "__text": " ElectricStation1\n\n\n\n\n"
        },
        "__text": " MAIN\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give the json example data?

Comment: I didn't write the json data. but I can get it using a converter. ill put it above from a converter.

Comment: change the ajax to 
    `$.ajax({
            url: "test.json",
      dataType: 'json',
            success: function(tree) {} });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried writing the parser, Hope it helps.

The Json, is the same file that you have posted

The complete Javascript code,

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(tree) {
                    traverse($('#treeView'), tree)
                    $('#treeView li:has(li)').addClass("Max").click(function(e) {
                            $(this).toggleClass("Max Min");
                            $(this).children("ul").toggle();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                    })

                    $("[href]").addClass("Blue").click(function(e){
                        $(this).toggleClass("Purple");
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")
                    })
                    $('#treeView li').click(function(g) {
                        var mytree2 = $(this);
                        mytree2.children('li').toggle();
                        g.stopPropagation();
                    })
                }
            })
        });
        function traverse(node, o) {
            for (var i in o) {
                if(i == "__text" || i == "_href")
                    continue;
                if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
                    if(o[i].__text){ 
                        var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                        var node=$('<li>').appendTo(ul)
                        if(o[i]._href){
                            var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                            $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
                        }else{
                            $(node).text(o[i].__text)
                        }
                    }
                    traverse(node,o[i]);
                }
                else{
                    var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                    if(o[i].__text){
                        var li = $('<li>' + o[i].__text + '<\/li>').appendTo(ul)
                        if(o[i]._href){
                            var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                            $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
                        }
                    }else{
                            $('<li>' + o[i] + '</li>').appendTo(ul)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Also i have changed the treeView unordered list to div.

```
<body>
    <div id="treeView">
    </div>
</body>
```

**[EDIT]**

```
function traverse(data) {    
    if (typeof(data) == 'object') {        
        var ul = $('<ul>');
        for (var i in data) {
            if(i == "__text" || i == "_href" || i == "_attr")
                continue;
            if(data[i].__text){
                ul.append($('<li>').text(data[i].__text).append(traverse(data[i])));         
            }
            else{
                ul.append(traverse(data[i]));
            }
        }        
        return ul;
    } else {       
        var textNode = $('<li>').text(data);
        return textNode;
    }
}
```

also change

```
traverse($('#treeView'), tree)
```

to

```
$('#treeView').append(traverse(tree))
```

in the ajax success function. I haven't handled for the attr and http. you can add it in the same way as the previous function.

Comment: do u have any idea why the blue and purple classes are not working in the original xml html file?

Comment: I do not have much experience with json, I work with firefox, it has its own developer tool but i use Fire bug, you can find it under the add ons. Using this you can debug your scripts and more. Initially add break points and log statement. This is what helped me.

Comment: I haven't looked into the blue purple issue. If I do will try to help you with that. What was the issue you were facing there?

Comment: $("[href]").addClass("Blue").click(function(){

                    $(this).toggleClass("Purple");
                    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href")

                    })

Comment: its for the links, so they are shown as blue and underlined, and when clicked they become purple. it worked the first few times then stopped so its weird. addClass Blue is working in the JSON file

Comment: is there a way I can call the objects in JSON like I did in xml? so .MainStation.Max class will work and ouput an image like its does for the xml.

Comment: you can do it. You will have to modify the script for that i guess.

Comment: I am not facing the blue purple issue.

Comment: yea nevermind I tried it with firefox and its working. but not with IE

Comment: hey ace I was working with the tree and I just noticed that the output is incorrect. the branches are not as they should be, for example Mainstation2 shouldn't be a child of MainStations 1 but it should be equal to it (another branch of same type MainStation). ill post the code I have now. its not working well before or after my changes

Comment: Oh yes i noticed the issue, yes some changes in the traverse function may give you the right result.

Comment: any idea wheres the issue? i tried disabling each line alone but it didnt help show where the issue comes from. im assuming its from the 1st if(o[i].__text) branch.

Comment: sorry ace i shoulda commented i fixed the issue. i just had to move var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node) to before the for loop. couldnt have done this without u tho i appreciate it.

Comment: u know an easy way to make the nodes expand only when i click on the + and -, so that when i click on them it only opens html or attr but doesnt expand? if it needs an algorithm forget it uve done enough :) whats ur thing on this website btw if i may ask?

Comment: add `$('<span><\/span>').addClass("Max").prependTo('#treeView li:has(li)')` and change the click handlers to `$('.Max,.Min').click(function (e) {})` you may need to change the content in the function so it will toggle the sibblings children on click of the span.